# ASP.NET MVC Only HttpPost Actions in a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

EDIT -

Is there a way I dont have to annonate all actions inside a controller to be POST methods, and define it once per controller?

I know we can do that by individually annotating the `[HttpPost]` attribute over the action methods

```
public class HomeController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Method1 (object abc)
    {
       //blah 
       //blah

       return blah
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Method2 (object abc)
    {
       //blah 
       //blah

       return blah
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Method3 (object abc)
    {
       //blah 
       //blah

       return blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Better?  Cleaner?  What's wrong with attributes?  Do I not know something about them?  Do they come over and drink all your liquor?  I don't get it.

Comment: What exactly isn't clean about a method being annotated with what type of verb that action is attainable with. I'd posit that if you have a controller full of post actions, you're probably not looking at the right thing to be cleaning

Comment: @Igor - I already tried at the controller level, HttpPost is only valid on 'method' declarations

Comment: @will you are funny.. what I meant was if I have all my actions are POST methods.. I dont like the way I have to annotate each method with the HttpPost attribute...  do you know of a way I dont have to do that and just define it once

Comment: I agree with @Will But if you really want to do this for any reason, you might consider creating an action filter to check request headers and do whatever you want and apply that in the controller level.

Comment: The HttpPostAttribute is scoped to methods, so you can't apply it to the class.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.118).aspx You might be able to prefix your method names with Post (e.g., PostMethod3), but that might confuse MVC's default route-determinator-thingy (which is frankly dumb as a POST).  Personally, I like attributes.  They're always the life of the party.

Comment: You could create a custom ActionFilter that inspect the http METHOD and if request is not POST it returns Not Found. You can apply that filter to the class which would apply to all action on the controller.

Comment: You do not have to attribute the actions at all, but then they are also reachable with other HTTP verbs.